# Add label to top of axis using Tikz Picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, tikz-node, axis

I am trying to find a better way to add a letter above each point on a simple single axis.  I got the result I needed using this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
\clip(-8,-1) rectangle (5.5,2);
\draw[<->,color=black] (-5.4,0.) -- (5.4,0.);
\foreach \x in {-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5}
\draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt) node[below] {\footnotesize $\x$};
\draw[color=black] (-5,.4) node {$A$};
\draw[color=black] (-4,.4) node {$B$};
\draw[color=black] (-3,.4) node {$C$};
\draw[color=black] (-2,.4) node {$D$};
\draw[color=black] (-1,.4) node {$E$};
\draw[color=black] (0,.4) node {$F$};
\draw[color=black] (1,.4) node {$G$};
\draw[color=black] (2,.4) node {$H$};
\draw[color=black] (3,.4) node {$I$};
\draw[color=black] (4,.4) node {$J$};
\draw[color=black] (5,.4) node {$K$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

but I have to imagine there is a less "brute-forcey" way to do it.  Any suggestions?  (P.S. I am very new at this).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you give up on half of way ... you should exploit introduced loop:

```
\documentclass[tikz,
               border=3mm,
               ]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
% axis
\draw[<->] (-5.4,0.) -- (5.4,0.);
% ticks with labels
\foreach \x [count=\xx from -5] in {A,B,...,K}
    \draw (\xx,1mm) node[above] {$\x$}
                    -- + (0,-2mm)
                    node[below,font=\footnotesize] { $\xx$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect!  I figured there had to be a way to use the loop, but I wasn't really sure how to introduce another variable to get both the numbering and the letters in there.  Thank you!